# Get the information of each matching row on JOIN query

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have this query :

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id,b.*,c.* 
        FROM table1 a 
             left join table2 b on a.id=b.id1 
             left join table3 c on a.id = c.id2 
        WHERE b.field='name' and a.id=$id 
        GROUP BY c.id";
```

The problem is that from `table3` (or `table c`) I have 5 matching rows on that condition `(a.id = c.id2)` and in the final result I have information  only from one of the matching rows. What should be my `GROUP BY` clause so I can get the data from all 5 matching rows from `table c`, not only the data from the first matching row?

Comment: _Beware_ the use of `GROUP BY` on only one column  when you have several in the `SELECT` list. MySQL permits this by default where it is a compile error in most other RDBMS. The results you get on the other columns may be unpredictable.

Comment: Are you trying to get back a `DISTINCT` rowset? Since you have no aggregate functions (`SUM(), MAX(), COUNT()` etc) requiring the `GROUP BY` it seems that might be your intent.

Comment: with group by clause you should use only columns which are functionally dependent on the grouped columns

Comment: Yes i am trying to get 1 row from table2 and all data for the mathing 5 rows from table3.

Comment: The result is unpredictable with the level of details provided.  As you have specific `WHERE` condition, you better remove the "GROUP BY" and manually extract the result in desired format.

Comment: What we're saying is in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of `GROUP BY` is inappropriate.

Comment: Does `SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.*, c.*....` (with no `GROUP BY` at the end) not get you what you want?

Comment: Yeah, it gives the same result

Comment: We need sample data then.  Head over to http://sqlfiddle.com and build up a testable sample. Post what you currently have, and then edit above to add sample output of what you _want_ to get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id, b.*, c.* FROM table1 a 
   LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id1 
   LEFT JOIN table3 c ON a.id = c.id2 
   WHERE b.field='name' and a.id=$id 
   GROUP BY a.id, c.id";
```

It will group results having same pair (a.id, c.id).